# How do I convert an existing LibGDX project to Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, libgdx

I have an existing LibGDX game and as it gets more complex I started looking into Maven for project management. I'm completely new to Maven, I just read the basics tutorials, installed it and created some skeleton projects with it.

On [the LibGDX wiki page for Maven integration](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Maven-integration), it teaches how to create a new Libgdx project with maven integration, using [the LibGDX Maven Archetype](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-maven-archetype). But there's nothing the about how to use Maven integration on an existing project.

The skeleton project created by the Libgdx-maven archetype has a completely different directory structure from my project (created using libgdx's setup UI). Does that mean I have to manually copy all my existing project files into the new maven skeleton (and probably spend some quality hours fixing the problems that come from that)? Or is there some way to automatically convert my existing project to maven?

Comment: There is no way to do it automatically. You could also convert your current projects to maven projects, but then you would have to adjust the poms according to your current directory structure... Sometimes you just gotta do something yourself.

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a libgdx project using the libgdx maven archetype. Set the correct names and paths and copy the configuration to your existing project (or your old project into the new directory)